# Graph dependencies in tensorflow: how to validate that dependencies exist or not?

Tags: tensorflow

```
op1=tf.image.random_brightness(placeholder_img3d_float32, max_delta=...)
op2=tf.image.random_contrast(placeholder_img3d_float32, lower=..., upper=...)
op3=tf.image.per_image_standardization(placeholder_img3d_float32)
```

If I defined these 3 ops, and then I run:

```
sess.run(op1, ...)
sess.run(op2, ...)
sess.run(op3, ...)
```

vs. running: `sess.run([op1, op2, op3], ...)`

- Would I have executed all 3 ops 3 times? Or are they all independent, thus the 3 runs each ran just the op I requested?
- How should I validate graph dependency questions like this?

Update:

The tensorboard graph of those 3 ops looks like there are no dependencies between them, but the `local_placeholder` shown in the top right has 5 outputs, at least one that feeds each of the 3 ops here. Does that mean that when I feed the placeholder it will run the 3 ops, or are the lack of dependencies shown in the graph telling me that although the placeholder is common, there are no dependencies and only the op call with be processed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a session you can give the command to run all 3 operations same time. But inside of the tensorflow will automatically looks for dependencies.

Let's say your 3rd operation depends on 2nd operation and 2nd operations depends on 1st operation and you need to run 3rd operation first, then session object will try to run the first operation first and try to fill dependencies and then come to other steps.

In the tensorflow graph you can observe the dependencies nicely. Each gray line will show you the data flow between two operations. And dotted line will show the dependencies for each variables.